# How can I change the HTML code via VB .Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I change the HTML code via VB .Net code?

For example,

on .aspx file I have:

```
<div class="Menu_On"><asp:LinkButton ID="Link_Menu1" runat="server">Menu 1</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div class="Menu_Off"><asp:LinkButton ID="Link_Menu2" runat="server">Menu 2</asp:LinkButton></div>
<div class="Menu_Off"><asp:LinkButton ID="Link_Menu3" runat="server">Menu 3</asp:LinkButton></div>
```

Then, when I click the "**Menu 2**" link, the class which coping the link should change become "**Menu_On**", and the other class become "**Menu_Off**".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9922863/370103) has pointed out, you should run the elements server-side:

```
<div id="divMenu1" runat="server" class="Menu_On">....
<div id="divMenu2" runat="server" class="Menu_Off">....
<div id="divMenu3" runat="server" class="Menu_Off">....
```

Then in `Link_Menu2` click event, you can do:

```
divMenu1.Attributes("class") = "Menu_Off"
divMenu2.Attributes("class") = "Menu_On"
divMenu3.Attributes("class") = "Menu_Off"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add `runat="server"` and `ID` to the div's you can access them from code-behind.